# JPA Inbound Channel Adapter - QueryDsl / javax.persistence.Query support

Tags: spring-integration

In my team we love having type-safe queries thanks to QueryDsl.

We tried to make it work together with JPA Inbound Adapter without much success so far,
as the later only accepts String queries (namedQuery, nativeQuery, jpaQuery).

I was wondering if it could be possible to make the JPA Inbound Adapter accept `javax.persistence.Query` rigth away instead of only String queries, which would allow the following:

```java
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public JpaInboundChannelAdapterSpec getInboundAdapter() {

    JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
    Query query = jpaQueryFactory.selectFrom(qFoo).where(qFoo.bar.eq("john")).createQuery();

    return Jpa.inboundAdapter(entityManager)
            .query(query);
}
```

There seems to be an alternative solution using a combination of `Query.unwrap()` and Jpa inbound adapter's `.parameterSource()`
but it is more complex and I am not done figuring it out. I'll update the post if I'll make it work.

```java
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.integration.jpa.support.parametersource.PositionSupportingParameterSource;

public JpaInboundChannelAdapterSpec getInboundAdapter() {

    JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
    Query query = jpaQueryFactory.selectFrom(qFoo).where(qFoo.bar.eq("john")).createQuery();
            
    String jpql = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).getQueryString();
    
    //TODO: Create an implementation of PositionSupportingParameterSource
    PositionSupportingParameterSource paramaterSource = new todo(query.getParameters);

    return Jpa.inboundAdapter(entityManager)
                .jpaQuery(jpql)
                .parameterSource(paramaterSource);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as far as I see we do in the end just this `query.getResultList()`, or this `query.executeUpdate()`. So, as long as you are concerned there is no reason in a `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` for your use-case at all. There is just enough to use a plain `MessageSource` impl with that your `JPAQueryFactory` and `getResultList()` as a return from a source. We also support a `Supplier` configuration for an `@InboundChannelAdapter` or `IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier()` for Java DSL:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#functions-support

Comment: Many thanks Artem. Using MessageSource is the way to go :)